# how to create installer file

Tags: c++, installation

I am currectly finishing my project in C++ and i'm looking for a way to create my own C++ installer file
which will create the project dll's and exe files into a specific path

what is the easier way to learn how to do it?

Comment: And I always recommend [Inno Setup](http://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=inno%20setup&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php&ei=9aDQTrnfAa3T4QTBxMlm&usg=AFQjCNG06FRqGUElmljRtLb7Jzd3z43Unw&sig2=9X3EqVL-r4fP7zQZizSpSA)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to build an installer. While you can of course always make one yourself, you should google for something like "create an installer". Some prebuilt solutions include "InstallShield", or the ".msi" file format, which you can create on your own using something like "Advanced Installer".

Of course, if you want your users to build your project from source, then you need a makefile and to make sure you bundle all the libraries. There are also kits like autotools to do that for you.

Comment: The irony of this answer being the first link Google suggests when following the answer's suggestion of googling how to do it...

Answer (score 3):

If you use VS 2010, Installshield LE would suffice as it is integrated into VS 2010.
If you have access to Installshield IDE, there is nothing better available for your packaging needs.

There are two ways of packaging:

```
a) The LEGACY way

b) The Windows Installer way, Basic MSI is the keyword here.
```

The LEGACY way involves creating your own scripts for:

```
a) Installing the files to their locations

b) Writing registry entries, if needed

c) Registering COM components, if needed

d) Creating shortcuts etc...
```

Tools that can be used for LEGACY approach are:

```
a) NSIS - very good and has a scripting language of its own.

b) Installshield - has a project type called Installscript Project. Installscript is the scripting language to be used.
```

The Windows Installer way is a bit hard comapred to the LEGACY way.
One has to learn the basics of MSI technology which can be daunting.
The package created has .msi as extension. This file is a database that the developer configures and the Windows Installer takes care of all other things. This is called TRANSACTIONAL installation procedure.
Even the UI presented during install is configured in the Database using tables like Dialog, Controls etc...

Tools that can be used for Windows Installer approach are:

```
a) Installshield - has a project type called Basic MSI
b) Wix - Opensource and xml based. You configure appropriately named xml files and various utilities in the Wix package will help you to create an MSI package.
```

Answer (score 1):

First after completing your project click save. Second click on file tab,Add,New Project.

In new Project Click other Project types , Setup and Deployment and in that  You can click InstallShield LE or Visual Studio Installer.

Hope this Helped you

Answer (score 1):

I always recommend [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net). You might also investigate [HM Nis Edit](http://hmne.sourceforge.net) - it's an IDE for NSIS that has a useful wizard feature. It will generate an installer script for you which you can further customize. The documentation is extensive.

Answer (score 0):

can't believe no one mentioned install creator pro(there is also a free version with a branded message that displays after installing). Its feature set is pretty limited, though it has options for writing registry values and specifying custom paths to %AppData% or any other place you may want to install some files. it also has an optional wizard interface, and with each step you have the oppurtunity to preview each individual page.

the paid version offers the option for adding serial number/registration to your program. i've never tried it so i'm not sure how effective it may be. its also quite and expensive little program, but i would recommend it atleast to the beginner or someone who is more concerned with maintaining the codebase of their program and less concerned with how fancy and decorated their installer program is.

i know its been a long time since this was posted but for future reference this program is far easier for any beginner to creating installation packages for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Use Visual Studio as an .MSI installer creator. This solution is great for packaging for windows devices. Just keep in mind that you might not be able to package for some Unix systems. If you want a universal way to package a project you can try making a custom installer of your own (Recommended).

Comment: Just a suggestion. Nothing much.